# How to show multiple calendar events simultaneously?

Tags: calendar

The calendar layout has taken on a sort of TV schedule layout with the list of event locations along the y axis. The x axis displays times and the user would be able to click through time linearly with forward and back buttons to view events happening in the surrounding hours. The event locations will be limited to four or five and events are color coded based five event types with corresponding icons. Currently each event has a rollover tooltip displaying additional information for the event.

I need to show events happening simultaneously at the different locations. What is the best way to handle this?

I will also need to include a map, but I'm concerned with proximity issues, namely keeping the elements close enough that they flow seamlessly together.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/43508178@N05/7592747056/in/photostream

Comment: It would be much more easier to understand and answer if u can provide a visual evidence.

Comment: I completely agree, but it won't let me upload a photo since I'm a new user.

Comment: So do you mean that the same event is happening in 2 places or same time slot has 2 events in the same location

Comment: To clarify, the same time slot has two events happening at the same location.

Answer (score 6):

I work at an online scheduling software company (I hope you don't :) so I hope my answer is worth it's salt.

[image: mocked mock]

For simultaneous events, you need to separate each location into as many slots as the location can handle. A design like location one would be ideal but it gets tricky fast when events don't start or end on the same time. Engineering will quickly get fierce. Location 2 shows two slots working.

Since you pop up information on hover (I recommend click) Event slots can be rather thin and minimal.

For the map... how about click the map text or icon?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. It is an obvious and simple solution now that I see it. I am trying out the Location 1 example with my content.